# Find specific text in a file and replace that

Tags: c#, wpf, replace

I'm building a WPF program that is editing save-files for a simulation program to make it easier to adjust certain parameters. The structure of that (txt)file looks like this

```
{Verdieping 1}

A bunch of data

'Max'
15
20
10
]);

More data

{Verdieping 2}

A bunch of data

'Max'
25
10
40
20
]);

More data

{Verdieping 3}

etc.
```

Because the name of the list I need is always 'Max' i cannot use `Replace("Old_Value", "New_Value");` So I need someway to find the header {Verdieping 1} then look for 'Max" and write the values down until it reaches *"]);"* so i end up with something like this:

```
Verdieping_1[0] = 15
Verdieping_1[1] = 20
Verdieping_1[0] = 10

Verdieping_2[0] = 25
Verdieping_2[1] = 10
Verdieping_2[2] = 40
Verdieping_2[3] = 20
```

Then when I change these values I need to write them back into the file in the correct locations. Right now I'm using this code in order to read and ultimately write the new file:

```
var Model = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Base_Model.txt");

//format code here...

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\New_Model.txt", Model);
```

Could somebody give me some hints or help as to how I could best solve this?

**EDIT**
This is the actual file structure of the file I want to eddit:

```
{Atom: Verdieping 2}

int015(0, 64, [ 
1
2
3
]);
int015(1, 64, [`ActivityID`
20
21
33
]);
int015(2, 64, [`vtp`
139830296
189540320
169919424
]);
int015(3, 64, [`%`
100
100
100
]);
int015(4, 64, [`Max`
15
5
20
]);
int015(5, 64, [`Fill (1 = fill, 0 = empty)`
1
1
0
]);
SetStatus(0);
int018;


{Atom: Verdieping 2}

int015(0, 64, [ 
1
2
3
]);
int015(1, 64, [`ActivityID`
22
23
24
]);
int015(2, 64, [`vtp`
166058172
165557860
155960564
]);
int015(3, 64, [`%`
100
100
100
]);
int015(4, 64, [`Max`
15
20
10
]);
int015(5, 64, [`Fill (1 = fill, 0 = empty)`
0
1
1
]);
SetStatus(0);
int018;
```

The 'Max' I was talking about earlier is actually called:
    int015(4, 64, [`Max`

And as you can see that name is identical for each off the layers, the amount of variables are different tho.

Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: "Some ideas???" is sounds like parser.

Comment: sounds like you should be using Xml not text file

Comment: There should be some code to produce this text file. What is its algorithm/logic?

Comment: @L.B will a `regexp` help OP?

Comment: @bonCodigo maybe, but the skipped part (`A bunch of data`) may give us the structure of the text file. Without knowing the whole structure, all answers would be lame.

Comment: This file is generate by an other application, {Verdieping *} is the definition for a layer. So each {Verdieping *} is a different block that contains the data for that layer. I can't post the data in here since it holds to many characters. However, i might also be helped if there is a way tho change by line number...??

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(fileName), @"\[`Max`(.*?)\]", RegexOptions.Singleline)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value.Split(" \t\n\r".ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            .ToList();

foreach (var v in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", v));
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
15, 5, 20
15, 20, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex maybe? I made this fast answer, which shouldn't be copy pasted, however; you can consider the results.

In this answer I am expecting your array to be in chronological order to prevent the source code from being too long and messy.

The file I read for the 'DataContainer' objects look identical with the file below:

```
{Verdieping 1}

A bunch of data

'Max'
15
20
10
]);

More data

{Verdieping 2}

A bunch of data

'Max'
25
10
40
20
]);
```

First of all I find each 'Max' in the string
Then I take all the datas below and print them out

The regex used to find this is: `\'Max\'.*?\]\);`

Try this code out to see the results

```
// fill our container
            string DataContainer = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "TestFile.txt"))) {
                DataContainer = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            // print data
            Match regMatch = Regex.Match(DataContainer, @"\'Max\'.*?\]\);", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            int verdiepc = 0;
            while (regMatch.Success) {
                string[] Data = regMatch.Value.Replace("\r", "").Split('\n');

                for (int I = 1; I < Data.Length - 1; I++) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Verdieping_{0}[{1}] = {2}"
                        , verdiepc, I, Data[I]);
                }
                Console.Write("\n");

                verdiepc ++;
                regMatch = regMatch.NextMatch();
            }

            // prevent immidiate exit
            Console.ReadKey();
```

The output will be:

```
Verdieping_0[1] = 15
Verdieping_0[2] = 20
Verdieping_0[3] = 10

Verdieping_1[1] = 25
Verdieping_2[2] = 10
........ etc..
```

I hope you can use this answer. It is a sketch of how you can use Regex to parse the file

Answer (score 0):

```
        string LoadedFile = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Base_Model.txt");
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i < Int32.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            Match ma = Regex.Match(LoadedFile, "Verdieping " + i.ToString() + ".+?'Max'.*?([0-9].+?)[]][)];", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            if(!ma.Success)
            {
                break;
            }
            string a = ma.Result("$1");
            MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(a, "(\\d+?)\r\n", RegexOptions.Singleline);

            for (int j = 0; j < mc.Count; j++)
            {
                result.AppendLine(String.Format("Verdieping_{0}[{1}] = {2}", i, j, mc[j].Result("$1")));
            }
            result.AppendLine(String.Empty);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\New_Model.txt", result.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You may initialize a new `List` of `string` which will contain the required output. Then, read the file getting the information between the target section and inserting the values between `[` and `]);` into the `List` of `string`.

**Example**

```
static List<string> ReadFile(string Path, string Section)
{
    #region Declare Variables
    string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path); //Read Path into Lines
    int CurrentValue = 1; //Declare CurrentValue as an Integer of value 1
    List<string> RequiredValues = new List<string>(); //Initialize a new List of string of name RequiredValues
    #endregion
    #region Collect Information
    //Look through the section getting the data between [ and ]);
    for (int i = 0; i < Lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Lines[i].StartsWith("{" + Section + "}"))
        {
            i++;
            while (!Lines[i].StartsWith("{") && !Lines[i].EndsWith("}"))
            {
                i++;
                if (Lines.Length > i)
                {
                    if (Lines[i].Contains('['))
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {

                            i++;
                            if (Lines[i].Contains("]);"))
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            RequiredValues.Add(Section + "[" + CurrentValue.ToString() + "] = " + Lines[i]);
                            CurrentValue++;
                        }
                    }
                    RequiredValues.Add("");
                }
                else
                {
                    break; //Reached the end of the document
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
    return RequiredValues; //Return RequiredValues
}
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> Contents = ReadFile(@"C:\Base_Model.txt", "Atom: Verdieping 2");
    foreach (string str in Contents)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(str); //Write str to the trace listeners
    }
}
```

<sup>**Sample Input**</sup>

```
{Atom: Verdieping 2}

int015(0, 64, [ 
4
5
6
]);
int015(1, 64, [`ActivityID`
20
21
33
]);
int015(2, 64, [`vtp`
139830296
189540320
169919424
]);
int015(3, 64, [`%`
100
100
100
]);
int015(4, 64, [`Max`
15
5
20
]);
int015(5, 64, [`Fill (1 = fill, 0 = empty)`
1
1
0
]);
SetStatus(0);
int018;

{Atom: Verdieping 1}

int015(0, 64, [ 
1
2
3
]);
int015(1, 64, [`ActivityID`
22
23
24
]);
int015(2, 64, [`vtp`
166058172
165557860
155960564
]);
int015(3, 64, [`%`
100
100
100
]);
int015(4, 64, [`Max`
15
20
10
]);
int015(5, 64, [`Fill (1 = fill, 0 = empty)`
0
1
1
]);
SetStatus(0);
int018;
```

<sup>**Sample Output**</sup>

The following was returned from reading `Atom: Verdieping 2`

```
Atom: Verdieping 2[1] = 4
Atom: Verdieping 2[2] = 5
Atom: Verdieping 2[3] = 6

Atom: Verdieping 2[4] = 20
Atom: Verdieping 2[5] = 21
Atom: Verdieping 2[6] = 33

Atom: Verdieping 2[7] = 139830296
Atom: Verdieping 2[8] = 189540320
Atom: Verdieping 2[9] = 169919424

Atom: Verdieping 2[10] = 100
Atom: Verdieping 2[11] = 100
Atom: Verdieping 2[12] = 100

Atom: Verdieping 2[13] = 15
Atom: Verdieping 2[14] = 5
Atom: Verdieping 2[15] = 20

Atom: Verdieping 2[16] = 1
Atom: Verdieping 2[17] = 1
Atom: Verdieping 2[18] = 0
```

The following output was returned from reading `Atom: Verdieping 1`

```
Atom: Verdieping 1[1] = 1
Atom: Verdieping 1[2] = 2
Atom: Verdieping 1[3] = 3

Atom: Verdieping 1[4] = 22
Atom: Verdieping 1[5] = 23
Atom: Verdieping 1[6] = 24

Atom: Verdieping 1[7] = 166058172
Atom: Verdieping 1[8] = 165557860
Atom: Verdieping 1[9] = 155960564

Atom: Verdieping 1[10] = 100
Atom: Verdieping 1[11] = 100
Atom: Verdieping 1[12] = 100

Atom: Verdieping 1[13] = 15
Atom: Verdieping 1[14] = 20
Atom: Verdieping 1[15] = 10

Atom: Verdieping 1[16] = 0
Atom: Verdieping 1[17] = 1
Atom: Verdieping 1[18] = 1
```

**NOTICE**: Using this method, the application will only collect the information between the first section it meets even if you have two sections with the same name.

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)